# How do I make an svg size to fit its content?

Tags: svg

I am displaying playing cards using svgs. I do not want the svgs to scale and I don't know how many cards there will be. The cards have a fixed size though. [image: cards as svgs]

Is there a way I can easily make the svg container resize to fit the content? 
Thanks for pointers.

Comment: take a look at `viewBox` attribute in SVG...

Comment: Thanks @IshanMadhusanka, I have left the viewBox attribute away, because I do not want my cards to scale.

Comment: Do you want to shrink the extra space of the SVG container? I think you can easily do this by setting it's `width` and `height` attributes.

Answer (score 21):

There is no automatic way to do it. But the simplest approach would be to use the bounding box of the SVG contents, using `getBBox()`, then update the `width` and `height` from that.

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", resizeSVG);


function resizeSVG() {
  var  svg = document.getElementById("card-table");
  // Get the bounds of the SVG content
  var  bbox = svg.getBBox();
  // Update the width and height using the size of the contents
  svg.setAttribute("width", bbox.x + bbox.width + bbox.x);
  svg.setAttribute("height", bbox.y + bbox.height + bbox.y);
}
```

```css
svg {
  background: green;
}

.card {
  fill: white;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 2;
}
```

```html
<svg id="card-table" width="300" height="150">
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="35" height="50" class="card"/>
  <rect x="55" y="10" width="35" height="50" class="card"/>
  <rect x="100" y="10" width="35" height="50" class="card"/>
</svg>


<br>
<button id="btn">Resize SVG</button>
```

Comment: `bbox.x + bbox.width + bbox.x` -- I do not understand this. Why add two x's to width?

Comment: If it was just `x + width`, the SVG would end right at the RHS of the third rectangle.  Adding an extra `x` gives us a right margin that is equivalent to the left margin.

Comment: is there a way to make the SVG present like this automatically? (no need to resize it with JS, it's encoded in the svg image)

Comment: @minseong If the SVG content is fixed and static, then yes - just set the `viewBox`.  But if the content is dynamic, or you don't know the dimensions beforehand (like in this question), then no.

Answer (score 3):

A reusable function, pass in the SVG element, and it will "crop" its viewBox to the actual content.

```js
function cropSVG(svgEl) {
    // Get the bounds of the SVG content
    const bbox = svgEl.getBBox();
    // Set the viewport with these bounds
    svgEl.setAttribute("viewBox", `${bbox.x} ${bbox.y} ${bbox.width} ${bbox.height}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `viewBox` attribute to the full size and set coordinates to the diagram.
Once done, the viewBox scales to fit the `width` and `height` of the container.

You can dynamically change the `viewBox` dimensions using JavaScript.
so after the graphics are rendered, when you know the dimensions, you can set the respective boundaries to your SVG element.

```
<svg id="svgContainer" height="500" width="500" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
    <polygon points="100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198" style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:5;fill-rule:nonzero;" />
</svg>
<hr/>
<button onclick="setImageSize(300)">Large</button>
<button onclick="setImageSize(100)">Small</button>
<br/>
<button onclick="setViewBox('0 0 100 100')">viewBox - half</button>
<button onclick="setViewBox('0 0 200 200')">viewBox - full</button>
```

And using JavaScript,

```
<script>
    function setImageSize(width){
        console.log(width);
        document.getElementById("svgContainer").setAttribute("width", width);
    }

    function setViewBox(viewBoxProperties){
        document.getElementById("svgContainer").setAttribute("viewBox", viewBoxProperties);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! Finally, using js to calculate the correct size dynamically is what I did. I was just hoping it could be done without. By the way, I am not sure if it's a good idea to set height/width AND viewbox

Comment: It's a good idea to set **both** height/width AND viewbox. Setting height/width inline prevents that flash of unstyled content when you stylesheet hasn't been loaded. Setting viewbox is good for scaling the SVG in different screen sizes.